# Generate major.minor.patch version using Python's faker library

Tags: python, faker

I'm using the Python [faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) library to generate fake data for my unit tests.

I have a field which represents a version with the following structure:

```
MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH
```

Some possible values are:

```
1.0.0
3.639.22
0.1.2
```

How can I use the faker library to generate a random version string?

Comment: It already exposes helpers for generating integers: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.python.html#faker.providers.python.Provider.pyint. Get three, format a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method:

```
fake.numerify('%!!.%!!.%!!')
```

(note that in this example each part will always have at least 1 digit and max 3 digits, you can play around with that, see [`faker.numerify`](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/baseprovider.html?highlight=bothify#faker.providers.BaseProvider.numerify))